# Midori Dashboard (autostart) - no JavaScript

Tags: raspbian, midori

I set up a small dashboard via `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

```
@xset -dpms
@xset s off
@xset s noblank
@midori -e Fullscreen -a https://domain.tld
```

But it seems that JavaScript pages will not work. If I open a page URL with an autologin-API on the Pi itself the login (JavaScript) works. Via Autostart the login does not work.

Is there an option to turn JavaScript on/off?